# Is there a way to show that one line is shorter than another in Euclid?

Tags: geometry, elementary-number-theory, euclidean-geometry

Pretty simple.  Is there a definition in Euclidean geometry that says that one line segment is shorter than another?  In number theory $(<)$ is defined such that $a<b$ if and only if there exists a number $c$ such that $a+c=b$.  Is there an analog in Euclid's geometry?

Something like: given an $a,b\in \mathbb Q$ such that $a<b$ we can draw a line segment AB such that |AB|= $a$. Then it is possible to draw a point C on line AB such that |AC|= $b$ (this is analogous to "there exists a number $c$ such that $a+c=b$").  But I can't seem to restrict C from not being between A and B cause that would be similar to $a-c=b$.

My example may be way off. If that is too confusing just refer to the first paragraph.

Comment: We need some non-numerical axioms for what it means for segments AB, A'B' to be of equal length and what it means for C on the line thru A and B to be between A and C. See: Foundations Of Geometry by David Hilbert, and the chapter "Ordered Geometry" in Introduction To Geometry by Donald Coxeter.

Comment: That's perfect thanks for the references

Answer (score 1):

This is maybe a little rough but you can say that $a<b$ if and only if a circle of radius b centered at an end point of a line segment of length a does not not intersect the line segment of length a, I think.